# SQL запрос к нескольким таблицам и отдельный их вывод

Tags: mysql, sql

у меня есть около 20 таблиц с идентичной структурой и названиями полей. Различие только в названиях таблиц и наполнением. Подскажите как выполнить один SQL запрос, который получит их в виде ассоциативного массива, где каждая таблица будет отдельной, чтобы я могу потом отделить одну от другой.
Если на примере, то я хочу из вот таких запросов:
SELECT * FROM `work_exp`;
SELECT * FROM `workers_type`;
и т.д.
получить один длинный. Как мне это сделать?
БД - MYSQL

Comment: думаю union all??

Comment: @AzizUmarov, но `union all` возвращается данные в виде **целого единого результата**, а автор вопроса хотел, чтобы результат с каждой таблицы как-то разделялся (например, оборачивался в массив)

Comment: SELECT 'work_exp', work_exp.* FROM work_exp union all SELECT 'workers_type', workers_type.* FROM workers_type